# Image viewer for multiple images

Tags: software-rec, graphics, images

Is there any image viewer (like eog) for linux which can do the following:

Show 2 (3 or 4) images of a directory with maximal possible sizes on one page at the same time. When I click "next", it should show me the next 2 (3 or 4) images of that directory and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comic viewers (such as [Comical](http://comical.sf.net/), [Comix](http://comix.sf.net/), [QComicBook](http://qcomicbook.horisone.com/), or [cbrpager](http://jcoppens.com/soft/cbrpager/index.en.php)) usually have a double-page mode.

In addition, [Geeqie](http://geeqie.sf.net/) has two-image modes and a quadruple-image mode. However, the sub-windows seem to be independent of each other (when you change one, the others don't change).

Answer (score 3):

**Nomacs**

https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs

I was looking for something to replace Google Photos locally to help organize my photos.

I need to quickly browse image thumbnails and do basic edit operations like renaming, rotation and cropping, and Nomacs fit perfectly!

When you open a directory with:

```
sudo apt install nomacs
nomacs .
```

you get thumbnails like this:

[image]

Double click on an image and it becomes big:

[image]

Then from there you can:

- Shift-T: back to thumbnails
- Left Right arrow keys: move to previous / next photo
- C: crop with mouse. Once done:

  - Enter: apply the crop
  - Esc: abort the crop
  - Ctrl + Shift + S: save cropped image as a new file
  - Ctrl + S: overwrite original file
  - Ctrl + Z: undo edit
- R: rotate
- F2: rename

Here's what crop mode looks like for example:

[image]

Some shortcomings:

- doesn't support videos: https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/issues/191
- can't scan directories recursively: https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/issues/297

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, nomacs 3.12.

Answer (score 0):

Try GwenView  http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/overview

Picasa is also now available for Linux to download Picasa http://picasa.google.com/linux/

Comment: Thanks. Could you describe how to do in gwenview what I want?

Comment: http://gwenview.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php?action=view&album=/2.4&pos=0  Just use zoomin and zoomout at the right below of the window

Comment: That zooms maximal to 256x256 for me, that's to small.

Comment: may be picasa then? I have not tried gwenview more extensively as such before either.

Comment: Same problem with picasa

Answer (score 0):

Shotwell Photo Manager (https://shotwell-project.org/doc/html/) seems to be a good alternative.

It still runs on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS box.

[image: screenshot of shotwell]

Answer (score -2):

You can use MulimgViewer. (This is my repository).

MulimgViewer is a multi-image viewer that can open multiple images in one interface, which is convenient for image comparison and image stitching.

MulimgViewer supports sequential and parallel mode to display image.

MulimgViewer is implemented in python and currently provides Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 versions.

GitHub: https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer

Wiki: https://github.com/nachifur/MulimgViewer/wiki

[image]

Comment: Why is the .deb ~ 60 MB and contains a whole lot of binaries?

Comment: And it only contains stuff in /etc and a broken .deb in the root directory.

Comment: In order to put the program files in a folder, so there is only /etc. This may not be the standard packaging process. If you have better suggestions, please let me know, thank you for your guidance. I can run the program through ”/etc/Mulimg_viewer/main“ on ubuntu18.04, have you reported an error? Please report this issue on github, thank you for your feedback.(https://github.com/nachifur/Mulimg_viewer/issues)

Comment: I dpkg by "pyinstaller main.py", maybe pyinstaller generate unnecessary file.

1./usr/bin/pip3 install wxpython pillow pytest-shutil pyinstaller

2.pyinstaller main.py

3.dpkg -b . Mulimg_viewer.deb

4.install: dpkg -i ./Mulimg_viewer.deb

5.run: /etc/Mulimg_viewer/main

Comment: I am not proficient in packaging technology, the software has no uninstall function, you can delete /etc/Mulimg_viewer directly.

Comment: You can also choose to use the python source code to run the program(python main.py)
https://github.com/nachifur/Mulimg_viewer/wiki.

Comment: If you are not proficient at packacking, then why would you provide a package?  And also why would you use Pyinstaller for open source sofrware for a platform where Python is pre installed. // The source code itself looks fine, just distribute that for *nix.

Comment: The software is open source and free. If you don't contribute for it to improve the packaging process, I can only provide deb files in my way. First, I did not force you to use deb files. Second, others may want to use deb files. If you have any running errors, look forward to your feedback on github, thank you for your guidance.

Comment: If you are interested in improving this software, you can develop it with me, thank you for your attention.